# residualPlots - Why does it make no difference whether I use type = "response" or type "pearson"?

Tags: r, linear-regression

If I use `type = "response"`, the Y-axis should actually show: real value minus estimated value.

In my case, for example, the following values would be plotted on the Y-axis:

1 (real value) - 1.2 (estimated value) = 0.2 or 2 (real value) - 1.2 (estimated value) = 0.8.

With Pearson residuals, the residuals would have to be divided by a value, which would produce other values. However, with `type = "resonse"` and `type = "pearson"` the graphs look exactly the same.

It is not clear to me by which value exactly the residuals are divided. The description says: "pearson residuals are weighted residuals, scaled by the square root of the weights used in fitting." Here it is said that they are divided by the estimated standard deviation of Y https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-020-01055-2#Tab1 ). I am a little confused.

In a linear regression, how is the normal Pearson residual calculated and how is the standardised Pearson residual calculated? What are the properties of the normal PR (mean and SD) and what are the properties of the standardised PR (mean and SD)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You seem to be asking statistical questions, not programming questions. For help understanding how residuals are calculated from models, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead.